# About the definition of homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

can someone explaine me this definition of Homology:

"The homology groups of $X$ measure "how-far" the chain complex associated to $X$ is from being exact."

I know that homology measure the number of the holes, and the holes are given by the cycle...

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This was going to be a comment but it does not quite fit.

It sound like your question has something to do with bridging the divide between an intuitive or "picture" understanding of homology and the formal definition of singular or simplicial homology in the language of chain complexes.

You can of course define homology without using the language of chain complexes (stable homotopy of the eilenberg-maclane spectrum smash a space is one, but there are others, including bordism theories).

It sounds like you're hovering around the issue of why should a "boundaryless object that is not itself a boundary" (i.e. homology of a chain complex) really represent *holes*.   The short answer -- any "boundaryless" object is canonically the boundary of another object -- that other object is the *cone* on your original object.   So one has a *hole* in a space $X$ if you can find a closed "subobject" $Y$ in it, so that the inclusion map $Y \to X$ does not extend to a continuous function $CY \to X$ where $CY$ is the cone.

If you think about it, this is basically what inexactness of the chain complex is measuring.  Although the "cone" abstractly exists, there may be no way for it to exist *in the space you are studying* ($X$).

In a way I've just translated the notion of "hole" to another standard construct in algebraic topology -- *the extension problem*.   Homotopy groups of a space are more canonical examples of extension problems describing *holes*.

Answer (score 2):

If a complex is exact, its homology is zero. It follows that if its homology is non-zero, the complex is not exact and, intuitively, the larger the homology, the farther the complex is from being exact. There is nothing more than this.

Comment: what is the relation between this definition and "the homology measure the number of the holes" please

Comment: "The homology measures the number of holes" does not mean anything. At most, the number of holes is defined to be (the rank of) homology, or something.

Comment: but the holes are defined by cycles

Comment: Well, if holes are defined to be cycles, then it is not true that homology measures the number of holes, because there are usually more cycles than homology...

Comment: That phrase is just a hand-wavy attempt to make something have some intuitive content; it is a very bad one.

Comment: More precise would be to say that homology counts the number of types of holes. But then you have to define both what you mean by hole and what it means for two holes to have the same type... Well: thatis precisely the definition of homology, so the phrase does not help in any way.

Comment: Spanier sayed something bad?, why "there are usually more cycles than homology" please

Comment: I suggest you wait a bit more, learn a bit more of algebraic topology and *then* try to adjust your intuitions.

Comment: Spanier did not say anything wrong, but it is pointless. Homology was constructed **precisely** in order to make it possible for the phrase «the number of wholes» to have a definite sense. What you want to understand is, mostly, just circular.

Comment: juste tell me homology is the quotient between cycles and edges why homology is more cycles then homology ?

Comment: because the homology is a **quotient** of the group of all cycles by a usually non-trivial subgroup. Rarely a space has *no* cycles, but there are tons of spacees with no homology: it follows that usually there are more cycles than homology. As I said, I suggest you read a bit more.